# Recreating the logitech ghub sphere in shader nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

I've been trying to come up with a way to recreate the effect used in the image shown below:

[image: logitech ghub sphere]

An animated version can be found [here](https://resource.logitechg.com/w_1920,c_limit,f_auto,dpr_1.0,q_auto:best/content/dam/gaming/en/ghub-update/ghub-bg-video.mp4) or on the [logitech ghub download page](https://www.logitechg.com/en-us/innovation/g-hub.html).

[image]

As far as I can tell the effect consists of two layers, both covering the sphere in little dots effected by a flow map, which is also used for the plasma effect.

I'm having some problems with projecting the little dots in combination with a flow map without smearing out the effect. Is this even possible with shaders or should I fallback to geometry nodes and render out a zillion physical elements to create this effect?

Comment: Definitely. The point instance of  Geometry nodes is super fast. Cycles is not meant for stuff like this and even in Eevee you'd most likely have to write your own shader.

Comment: @FrederikSteinmetz You cannot answer an *X* or *Y* question with *Definitely* or *yes* ;-)

Comment: Since Blender 3.1 Cycles can render a point cloud with millions of points really fast at a low sample count (https://youtu.be/kwpj7ZUtnac) The challenge will be how to colorize the points dynamically.